# Why can't Tailwind native color picker dialog show transparency and/or use transparency?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm attempting to use Tailwind and set up an admin section where the user could select a color that includes transparancy, ie:

#FFFFFFaa

or

rgb(250 235 215 / 74%)

However it seems to not take with the color picker dialog or when using a default value that has transparency? Can't seem to find any explanation anywhere..would love some input! Perhaps type="color" could be set to something different? Currently using the following to bring up the color picker dialog:

```
<input id="custom_header_text_color" type="color" class="" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question seems to be about tailwind but the code you posted is just a vanilla color picker which, as mentioned in the answers and mdn doc, does not support transparency.

Answer (score 0):

The value of an  element of type color is always a string which contains a 7-character string specifying an RGB color in hexadecimal format. While you can input the color in either upper- or lower-case, it will be stored in lower-case form. The value is never in any other form, and is never empty.

Note: Setting the value to anything that isn't a valid, fully-opaque, RGB color in hexadecimal notation will result in the value being set to #000000. In particular, you can't use CSS's standardized color names, or any CSS function syntax, to set the value. This makes sense when you keep in mind that HTML and CSS are separate languages and specifications. In addition, colors with an alpha channel are not supported; specifying a color in 9-character hexadecimal notation (e.g. #009900aa) will also result in the color being set to #000000.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#value